# How to give Expander Full Width of Column in a Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, expander

I have an `Expander` and it should receive the full width of the column but I cant get it to work.

I tried to add the `Horizontal(Content)Alignment = stretch` on the `TextBlock` and on the `Expander` itself even on the `Grid`, but it is not working.

What I need is that the `Expander` takes about 90% of the width and the rest are assigned to the buttons as in the following example:

[image: Example of Expander items taking up full width in a ListView.]

I want to display e.g. a name and when you press on it, expands down and shows additional information
and if the buttons are pressed, then the commands behind the buttons will be executed (no commands are binded in the example).

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding log}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Expander Grid.Column="0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              IsExpanded="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                              Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="16"
                            Foreground="White"
                            Text="{Binding Description}" />
                    </Expander>

                    <Button Grid.Column="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource IconButton}">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../icons/edit.png"
                                        Stretch="None" />
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    <dialogButton:ConfirmButton Grid.Column="2"
                                                Question="{x:Static language:Strings.confirm}"
                                                Style="{DynamicResource IconButton}"
                                                Margin="0,0,10,0">
                        <dialogButton:ConfirmButton.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../icons/delete.png"
                                        Stretch="None" />
                        </dialogButton:ConfirmButton.Background>
                    </dialogButton:ConfirmButton>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Styles

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" MinHeight="0" MinWidth="0" Margin="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Down">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I also tried things from the following Threads

[wpf - Header of Expander fit contents width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354858/wpf-header-of-expander-fit-contents-width)

Problem here is that the `Button`s are pushed out of the view

Best Solution would be if the `Expander` just takes the width of the column so that I can adjust the widths of the element by the `Grid.ColumnDefinition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the *item container*, a [`ListViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listviewitem?view=net-5.0) does not stretch its content by default. You have to create an item container style in order to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```